# Warning about getting "X"es for 4-valued logic VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am getting a warning that an arithmetic operation have `X` so the result is will always be `X`, although I am initializing my signals to `0s`. Can anyone help?

N.B. I am getting `X` for `Z_count` and `RC_count_var`

```
--RC counter
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

Entity RC_counter2 is
    Port(load, Cplus, Cminus : In Std_logic;
        X: In std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) :="0000";
        Z_count: Out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) :="0000");
end Entity;

Architecture behav of RC_counter2 is
    signal RC_count_var: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    Begin
    process(Cplus, load)
        --variable RC_count_var: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";

        Begin
            if load = '1' then
                RC_count_var <= X;
            end if;

            if (Cplus'EVENT and Cplus = '1') then
                RC_count_var <= RC_count_var + 1;
            else
                RC_count_var <= RC_count_var;
            end if;

        end process;

    process(Cminus, load)
        Begin

          if load = '1' then
                      RC_count_var <= X;
              end if;

         if (Cminus'EVENT and Cminus = '1') then
                    RC_count_var <= RC_count_var - 1; 
             else
                    RC_count_var <=RC_count_var;
             end if;

    end process;
 Z_count <= RC_count_var;
 end Architecture;
```

Comment: Note: to test the code add a clock to `Cplus`; `Z_count` and `RC_count_var` should count up and if you add a clock to `Cminus`; `Z_count` and `RC_count_var` should count down.

Comment: Not synthesizable. Please read up on synchronous logic design and use a clock.

Comment: To be precise, type 'std_logic' describes 9-valued logic: 'U': uninitialized, 'X': strong drive, unknown logic value, '0': strong drive, logic zero, '1': strong drive, logic one, 'Z': high impedance, 'W': weak drive, unknown logic value, 'L': weak drive, logic zero, 'H': weak drive, logic one, '-': don't care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `RC_Count_var` becomes invalid because it has multiple conflicting drivers.

In VHDL, whenever a signal is assigned in more than one process, it implies multiple drivers. These are usually not supported for synthesis and not recommended altogether. To make sure you do not have multiple drivers, simply makes all assignations to a signal in a single process.

Moreover, while not exactly wrong or problematic, I suggest you modify the following code:

```
if load = '1' then
    RC_count_var <= X;
end if;

if (Cplus'EVENT and Cplus = '1') then
    RC_count_var <= RC_count_var + 1;
else
    RC_count_var <= RC_count_var;
end if;
```

This doesn't gives multiple drivers, but has several problems. First, successive assignments to the same signal in a process overrides previous one. Thus, if `cplus` is rising and `load` is `'1'`, the value doesn't get loaded. It is much better and cleaner to use `elsif` or `else`. Also, synthesis target doesn't usually support asynchronous load. Asynchronous set/reset is fine, but asynchronous load to the value `X`, in your case, is likely problematic.